# Error: failed due to the following error: 80040154 when i call Req() class

Tags: asp.net, hp-quality-center

I use OTAClient.dll from HP for conencting with Quality Center.
My connection is correct:

```
TDConnection tdCon = new TDConnection();
tdCon.InitConnectionEx("http://....");
tdCon.Login("username", "userpass");
tdCon.Connect("****", "********");
```

But in this area i get error:

```
Req newReq = new Req();
```

I set platform target in x86 but didn't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `COM` object use the rest library. You could send xml documents with parameters for creating and updating requirements(`Req`) in QC. You can find documentation in QC.
You will use `"post"` method by `HttpWebRequest` for creating and updating, `"get"` method for getting session parameters. 
In the rest library look to creating entity description. For maintaining connections you must save QCSessionId. Look to authentication description.
Good luck!

Comment: I found documentation but it hard to understand. Could you throw me I simple example?